# How to recognize whether app built via PhoneGap webview/Titanium/Native Java?

Tags: android, cordova, android-webview, titanium-mobile

I know this may be a weird question.It might get flagged but i would argue for the validity of such a question for the concise development of robust apps.

**How do we identify whether a particular android app was built using [Phonegap](http://phonegap.com/) or [Native Java](http://developer.android.com) or by cross platform [Native Javascript API of Titanium](http://appcelerator.com)?**

Comment: Do you have the APK available?

Comment: Let's say "Yes!".How would a Yes and No affect the answer ?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but there must be some apk decompilers out there.

Comment: are talking about them "legal" here? .If they are not then how bout you show me some

Comment: Use google. Seriously.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't fool proof, but looking inside the apk of a Phonegap and a Titanium app I have (renamed .apk to .zip) I notice that for Phonegap the assets folder has a js file named "cordova-" followed by a version number. In the Titanium app there is an org/appcelerator/titanium/build.properties file in it. The folder names already indicate it was built using Titanium and the build.properties file contains the string "#Generated by Titanium".

Comment: and if it is natively built then those files will be different?